# Passing value of a textfield to a label in swift

Tags: swift, label, textfield, option-type

I have a textfield and I want it to hide and show when a button is pressed, and I also want the text in the textfield to be passed to a label just underneath the textfield. I tried this :

```
 @IBAction func myfunction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if textfield.isHidden == true{
        textfield.isHidden = false
        }else{
            label.text = textfield.text
            textfield.isHidden = true
     }
 }
```

Apparently the hidding and showing part is working but the line

```
label.text = textfield.text
```

is not. I get an error like this "Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x10143fb50" and in the console I have "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Can someone help me please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your error, it seems that you try to affect with this line `label.text = textfield.text` the text from your textfield into label but the problem is that your textfield.text is nil.

That's why you have the error **unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

Your textfield is an Optional. It can have a value or nil. If you try to unwrap an optional value having nil you have this kind of error. 
The solution here is to unwrap safely the optional value with *Optional Binding* like this :

```
if let textInput = textfield.text {
  //There is a text in your textfield so we get it and put it on the label
  label.text = textInput 
} else {
  //textfield is nil so we can't put it on the label
  print("textfield is nil")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler code you may try. The nil-coalescing operator (*a* ?? *b*) unwraps an optional *a*. if it contains a value, or returns a default value *b* if *a* is nil.

```
@IBAction func myfunction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    label.text = textfield.text ?? "" 
}
```